# Changing video frame rate and keeping duration intact

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I am trying to segment a video file, transcode each of the segments and then stitch them all back to one. The process is working but I have noticed that the final file has a different duration than the original one. Probably because I am transcoding to a fixed frame rate which is different from the source frame rate.

To segment the video I use:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video_only.mp4 -c copy -flags -global_header -segment_time 50 -break_non_keyframes 0 -reset_timestamps 0 \
  -segment_list file_segs.list -segment_format mp4 -segment_list_type ffconcat -write_empty_segments 0 \
  -f segment file_seg-%d.mp4
```

Then, each segment is transcoded with this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $f -vcodec libx264 -vsync 1 -crf 18 -vf "fps=30" -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset:v fast -profile:v main -level:v 4.1 transcoded/$f
```

And finally, concat:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i file_segs.list -c:v copy -c:a copy -movflags +faststart video_final.mp4
```

I've tried using "-r 30" instead on the filter (-vf), the same result.
As this is a part of a transcoding system I prefer not to check for the input file fps before transcoding as it can be anything - variable fps too (which is not so easy to detect)

Is there any way I can keep the duration intact while changing the frame rate in this type of transcoding flow?

Comment: How much difference is there?

Comment: Current video I am on is 7:09 and the resulting file is 7:05 (source fps is lower than 30)